# Help importing .pdb file into Maple

Tags: maple

I realy know nothing about Maple, so any help would be nice. I am attempting to import a .pdb file into Maple, as part of converting some Mathematica code to Maple. I need something that that can accomplish something equivalent to the Import command in Mathematica. I have tried using readdata, ImportData and fopen with little success. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be of great help.

Comment: What is a .pdf file?  There are at least 4 different possibilities on http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/pdb.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in reader for any of the different kinds of .pdb files in Maple.
Two suggestions:

1. Ask your question again on mapleprimes.
2. Import it in Mathematica and export it again as XML, which Maple can read.

Comment: Along the same lines, if these PDB files contain protein conformations coming from the Protein Data Bank, then the same conformations can also be downloaded in XML format (called PDBML/XML) from www.pdb.org.